# How to split the detail section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

Using Crystal Report 7

I want to split the detail section

Table1

```
id name value

001 rajan 200
002 vijan 300
003 suresh 400
004 shamith 500
....
```

I want to view the table in crystal report below mentioned format

Crystal Report Details Section

```
001         002
rajan       Vijan  
200         300

003         004
suresh      Shamith
400         500
```

...
...

How to do this.

Any one give some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Crystal version that old but in all the versions i've used you can place the fields in any way horizontally or vertically on the report canvas- so that shouldn't be a problem.

To format in columns you can go into the section expert and tick "format with multiple columns" in the details section. Then on the columns tab enter the width of your column (to get two columns divid your page width in 2) and make sure "across then down" is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above might be for an older version of Crystal Reports.  I'm using Crystal Reports 2008, version 12.1.0 and this is the way to cause grouping like you need:

First of all, think of this layout change as if you were producing printed labels.  If you measure out the dimensions of the label (Height, Width, horizontal and vertical gap between labels) and then modify the general Details layout accordingly, you will then produce the desired results.

Go to: Section Expert | Details | Layout tab

there are 3 sections:  Detail Size, Gap Between Details, and Printing Direction.  The bottom section Number of Details Across page and Down page, get set based upon the entries from the other 3.